# Updated to discord.js v12, Unable to list all guilds

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I created a discord bot in discord.js v11 and have updated it to v12, all code seems to be working fine after minor tweaks but i have not been able to fix my code to list all guilds the bot is connected to, if anyone knows a way to do this during the boot of the bot in v12 id be happy for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `client` is your Discord [Client](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client), `client.guilds.cache` would be a [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection) of [Guild](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild)s your bot is in. See [`GuildManager#cache`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildManager?scrollTo=cache); it's exactly what you'd expect `client.guilds` to be in v11.

The same cache concept applies for each Manager.

Comment: Thats the issue, whenever i tried to define new GuildManager it gave me an error, i cant remember what it was as the bot has around 20 servers so i decided to remove the code termporarily, if you could help me just add a few lines to the bot startup code to read all the servers out as a list that would be wonderful
`js
client.on('ready', () => {
 reloadall("boot")
 client.user.setPresence({ activity: {name: "name"},status: "online"})
})
`

Comment: @Delphren Phox `console.log(client.guilds.cache.array())` would print an array of the client's guilds to the console. Also, you can set your client's initial presence by passing [ClientOptions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ClientOptions) as a parameter in the [Client](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client) constructor instead. That way it's already set for you when logging in the client. See docs for more details.

Comment: my previous code was `js  client.guilds.forEach((guild) => {
        console.log(" - " + guild.name)
    })`
and printed just the names, in seperate lines, not the entire object tree of each server
also what do you mean bu passing ClientOptions? im still learning more about js (this bot is only around 1000 lines) and would like the know what i would do to set the Presence as the bot loads.

Comment: @DelphrenPhox You can definitely use your previous code, but make sure you change it to `client.guilds.cache.forEach(...)` in light of this answer. As for the presence, you could change your existing code which creates the client to `new Discord.Client({ presence: <presence data from your first comment> })` (or `new Client(...)` if you destructured) instead of leaving the constructor parameters empty.

Comment: I tried changing the old code to use client.guilds.cache.forEach but got an error saying forEach is not a function

Comment: @DelphrenPhox Mind sharing what the result of `console.log(typeof client.guilds.cache)` is? Collections still extend Maps, and `Map#forEach()` certainly exists, so it sounds like `client.guilds.cache` is not what you're expecting it to be.

Comment: the console outputs 
`object
`

Comment: Weird, it seems to be outputting properly now? im not sure why but it is